# TLS termination (encryption/decrytion) via proxy for non HTTP protocol

Tags: ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy, haproxy

[image: Indicative architecture]

The protocol in question is the MRCP v2 protocol.

**Problem overview:**
The client sends MRCP/TLS requests, and the server can't understand these since it doesn't have the ability to perform a TLS handshake or encryption. I am hoping that HAProxy, or any other proxy (Nginx?) will decrypt these TLS packets, and send it to the server, to which the server can respond, and then HAProxy can encrypt and send it back to the client.

If possible, I also want a way to extend this to the SIP protocol. From what I understood of HAProxy, it can't do TLS termination for TCP (layer 4), only HTTP (layer 7). Is there any work around/alternative to this?

Comment: Note that with SIP such a simple approach might not work. Connections can be started from both sides, so somehow the TCP connection started by the non-TLS client has to be encapsulated in TLS. Also it can be necessary to adjust SIP URL and headers like Contact, Via, ... to translate between TLS and plain TCP.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for NGINX and its [ngx_stream_ssl_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_module.html). It allows you to encrypt arbitrary TCP traffic (doesn't have to be HTTP). No special installation is required. Just install NGINX and front it to your server instead of HAProxy or whatever TLS terminator. Configuration is straightforward:

```
stream {

    ...

    server {
        listen              12345 ssl;

        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-MD5;
        ssl_certificate     /usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.key;
        ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;

        ...
    }
}
```

Client -> NGINX (stream TLS termination) -> whichever TCP protocol.

NGINX will only do TLS encryption without inspecting the underlying protocol.